# How to remove some of default scope in Arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, arel

Let's say that I have several default scoping on table

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope where(:first_name => 'Allen')  # I know it's not realistic
  default_scope where(:last_name => 'Kim')     # I know it's not realistic
  default_scope where(:deleted_at => nil)
end

>> User.all
   User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` 
   WHERE `users`.`first_name` = 'Allen' 
   AND  `users`.`last_name` = 'Kim' AND (`users`.`deleted_at` IS NUL
```

L)

and when I want to find users with regardless of first_name , only I can do is unscope it and redefining the default scope again

```
User.unscoped.where(:deleted_at=>nil).where(:last_name=>"Kim")
```

Is there a way to unscope certain keys like the following?

```
User.unscoped(:first_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

No, `unscoped` does not accept parameters.
it seems that in your case you would be better off defining normal `scopes` (was: `named_scopes`).

you should use default_scopes only if you need the data *always* (or almost) as defined in the `default_scope`.